# how to add fancy bottom border

Tags: line-breaking, border, line

I have seen a beautiful "bottom line" in a LaTeX, PDF file, but I cannot find its command. I would appreciate if anyone could tell me how to add these kind of lines, shown below, in my document.

Thanks..[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you searched this site for the words "fleuron" and "fleurons"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a font with fleurons. Your examples seem to have been made with `fourier-orns`. Here are two propositions, a text-wide fancy line, and a short version, with one argument, the length of the line on both sides of the fleuron box. It would be easy to add colour.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier, fourier-orns}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\tailpiecerule{\begin{center}
  \hrulefill\raisebox{-0.4ex}{~\floweroneleft\,\floweroneright~}\hrulefill
\end{center}}
\newcommand\shorttailpiecerule[1]{\begin{center}
  \rule{#1}{0.6pt}\raisebox{-0.4ex}{~\floweroneleft\,\floweroneright~}\rule{#1}{0.6pt}
\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[6]
\tailpiecerule
\lipsum[11]
\shorttailpiecerule{2cm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant with another spacing and colour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{fourier, fourier-orns}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\tailpiecerule{\centerline{%
  \color{LightSteelBlue}\hrulefill\raisebox{-0.4ex}{~\color{NavyBlue}\floweroneleft\,\floweroneright~}\hrulefill}} 
\newcommand\shorttailpiecerule[1]{\centerline{\color{IndianRed}
      \rule{#1}{0.6pt}\raisebox{-0.4ex}{~\floweroneleft\,\floweroneright~}\rule{#1}{0.6pt}
   }}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[6]

\tailpiecerule

\lipsum[11]
\shorttailpiecerule{2cm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a very useful answer, but another question arose in my mind, and that's about changing the vertical space it produce before the fancy line. Is there any way to reduce that space, and also can we change the color of the line. I appreciate your answer beforehand.

Comment: I've added a variant with less spacing and colour (even a tailpiece with two colours, to show how easy it is).