How to get a footline as show in the image
How to get such a footline in my article


Welcome. // Well, by writing it? Honestly, we like to see your attempts here. Search for package fancyhdr , and follow some of its tags: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fancyhdr .

Maybe with package  : pgfornement

For the symbols have a look here https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf and search e.g. for Fleurons and Flowers, e.g. on p. 191 . How to use those fonts is described in the beginning. Search for usepackage in said document. // This solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326972/245790 shows one example.
